# blg module not being detected

Tags: opengl

i just started using bgl with blender scripting
and it's giving this error "AttributeError: module 'bgl' has no attribute 'GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX"
i just checked on API documentation and it's supposed to be there
any idea?

```
import bgl
'''code from API doc'''
xval, yval= 100, 40
# Get the scale of the view matrix
view_matrix = bgl.Buffer(bgl.GL_FLOAT, 16)
bgl.glGetFloatv(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, view_matrix)
f = 1.0 / view_matrix[0]

# Instead of the usual glRasterPos2i(xval, yval)
bgl.glRasterPos2f(xval * f, yval * f)
```